# How to set CSRF tokens in requestheader to pass in $.post method call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, csrf

I am working in Spring 3.x with CSRF. At the time of Jquery call, needs to set the tokens in requesetHeader otherwise getting CSRF "null" exception. So I tried to get the values in javascript function and able to get the token value and header value inside javascipt function, then i tried to set the token using following functionalities, none of them are worked.

**method 1:**

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$.post(
url,
beforeSend: function(xhr){
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
},
$(testform).serialize(),
function(data) {
async: false;
}).done(function(data){

});
```

**method 2:**

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$.post(
url,
headers: {header,token},
$(testform).serialize(),
function(data) {
async: false;
}).done(function(data){

});
```

Please suggest or help me out of this.

Updated with the following code,

**method 3:**

From the below code, am able to hit the controller succesfully but the response not forward to another jsp. am i missing anything in below code, please advice me.

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$.post(
url,
{_csrf_header : header, _csrf : token},
$(testform).serialize(),
function(data) {
async: false;
}).done(function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var csrf = $('input[name="_csrf"]').val();
        var contentResult=document.getElementById('divComboProductos');
        var comercio =$("#ddlComercio").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: [[@{'/comun/productos/obtener/'}]] + comercio,
            data:  { _csrf : csrf},
            dataType:'text',
            cache:false,
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response){
                contentResult.innerHTML=response;
            }                           
        });
```

Comment: You have to explain the code in your answer. Add some explanation on what you did with code.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding something like this to your page...

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

See this post...
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jqXHR.setRequestHeader+undefined